# Facebook Authentication and HTTPS - domain, ports, protocols must match

Tags: facebook, facebook-authentication

Seem to be having problems on my website since changing over to HTTPS.

If a user adds something to cart, and is on the checkout page and
 - logged into Facebook already
 - authorised with the app already

Clicking on the Facebook Login button will work - no problems.

If a user adds something to cart, and is on the checkout page and
 - not logged into Facebook already
 - previously authorised with the app

Click on the Facebook Login button will make the pop-up open, prompting their login details. After successfully being logged in to FB (checking by opening a new browser window) - I get this error in the console - this is what I guess is stopping it from working.

Note - this work perfectly in http..

Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL https://www.facebook.com/dialog/permissions.request?_path=permissions.request&app_id=115551305199328&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fs-static.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter.php%3Fversion%3D11%23cb%3Df368597038%26origin%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.iloveugly.net%252Ff21427b398%26domain%3Dwww.iloveugly.net%26relation%3Dopener%26frame%3Df280a13e4&sdk=joey&display=popup&response_type=token%2Csigned_request&domain=www.iloveugly.net&perms=publish_stream%2Cuser_likes&fbconnect=1&from_login=1&client_id=115551305199328 from frame with URL https://www.iloveugly.net/View-your-cart-content.html?page=shop.cart. Domains, protocols and ports must match.

from script connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js:78

website:

w w w . i l o v e u g l y . n e t

facebook app settings have the domain as the www.domain.net and the app URL as https://

**Question:** Why would I be getting this error, and how can I resolve it? Where can I look?

Comment: And what exactly do you want from us?

Comment: Sorry, Why would I be getting this error, and how can I resolve it? Where can I look?

Answer (score 1):

Check how you have set up your successful-login redirects. They should be also pointing to https.